# Grails Domain Object Retrieval

Tags: grails

I am building a review system and built up the following domain objects and associations:

Review.groovy

```
{global review attributes -- when, status, finished, etc.]

static hasMany = [employeeReview: EmployeeReview]
```

Employee.groovy

```
{general employee attribute data}

static hasMany = [employeeReview: EmployeeReview]
```

EmployeeReview.groovy - purpose of this object is to relate Review and Employee, and also identify a reviewer for each employee.

```
Employee employee
Employee reviewer
static belongsTo = [review: Review, employee: Employee]

static hasMany = [employeeProjectReview: EmployeeProjectReview]

static mappedBy = [employee: "none", reviewer: "none"]
```

EmployeeProjectReview.groovy - A employee can be assigned many projects

```
Project project  //not displayed here, just some general info related to a project

static hasMany = [projectReviewDetails: ProjectReviewDetails]
static belongsTo = [employeeReview: EmployeeReview]
```

ProjectReviewDetails.groovy - all the review info, multiple per project

```
static belongsTo = [employeeProjectReview: EmployeeProjectReview]
```

The data is imported from a variety of systems through admin actions.  Everything is saved as I would expect it to based on the above.

A couple of questions:

*Does the associations above seem appropriate.  I decided to not put the reviewer in the Employee object as that can change year to year.

*From the application standpoint, everything is built off EmployeeReview.  To make it simpler for the reviewers, I am building some REST services to return data to those screens when needed.  When I get an EmployeeReview instance using employee.id and audit.id, I get a lot more than I expected.  I really only need the domain objects (projects and project details) for that employee in that audit, and maybe a few attributes on the reviewer (name, email, phone).

I am doing eager reads and returning the deep JSON object.  What I get back is every EmployeeReview entry (from EmployeeReview / Review association) -- this is a significant amount of data.  I also noticed that I get the reviewer EmployeeReview association as well.  It's less data, but isn't needed.

I've read to reduce attributes down using custom converters, but still don't want to return data I won't use (querying all the projects for a reviewer, for example).

Short of writing the SQL myself, what can I do?

Comment: 1. Turn off eager loading, 2. Use custom marshllers, 3. Don't use deep unless you really need it. You might have better luck posting this question on code review. Since the question isn't a "problem" but rather "how can I improve this".

Comment: Please don't flag for migration either. I don't think this is a good Code Review question. This feels more like "Design Review" than "Code Review". This would likely be closed on Code Review.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Fair enough. Still a bit broad of a question for Stackoverflow.